# Color every second row of the table

Tags: html, css

I need to color every second row in my table. 
I would love it to look like on the attached image
Any ideas how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

EVEN AND ODD RULES

One way to improve the readability of large tables is to color alternating rows. For example, the table below has a light gray background for the even rows and white for the odd ones. The rules for that are extremely simple:

Css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

[Check here google 1st result](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)